# Executing millions of tasks in Java within a short period of time?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I need to execute around 8,000,000 tasks in Java. Each task runs in between 1 and 50 ms. I have tried executing these tasks serially using a loop and in parallel using a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Obviously, running them serially in a loop is a lot slower and then running them through a `ThreadPoolExecutor` has a significant performance gain. However, I am still not satisfied with the performance with the `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

I am able to run all 8,000,000 tasks using 15 threads on 4 cores. I am batching 50,000 tasks when submitting tasks to the `ThreadPoolExecutor`. I am allowing a 1000 ms timeout for the `ExecutorCompletionService` to return a result. After tuning my application with these parameters I am getting about 25 minutes to process all 8,000,000 tasks.

Is there some way for me to run my application any faster than 25 minutes, perhaps Hadoop (distributed system using multiple machines)? I am open to using some other technology or framework.

Comment: Hadoop or Cassandra may help, it depends on if you're running into [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law). Can your tasks be made more efficient?

Comment: you can just copy the application to 10 machines, divide the 8 million tasks into 10 sections, and click 'Run' 10 times on the 10 machines

Comment: Increasing the number of threads would help but that requires more number of cores as well to see any performance improvement.

Comment: Are you certain that your program is CPU bound?

Comment: are you throwing away objects that you create? anything you can reuse?

Comment: Having 8.000.000 ops per milisecond would need a frequency of 1.25 MHz... stupid question in my opinion....

Comment: if there is no significant IO in those tasks try running them on your GPU using jCUDA or OpenCL.

Comment: I assume you must be using a fixed thread pool, correct? Have you tried a cached thread pool?

Comment: You have made a fundamental error, which no amount of programming can correct. Whatever you do, those tasks take CPU time. Take the number of tasks, multiply by the average duration of a task and divide by the number of CPUs. That is the minimum time required.

Comment: there is more than one calculation error, as if you get 5ms task time (1<5<50ms as op said) and do the math, you get to (5ms * 8000000)/4 = 2.7 hours. Even if each task gets to the minimum the OP said (1ms) it takes on perfect no overhead conditions 33 minutes.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. Even though I am running this using ``ThreadPoolExecutor`` on 4 cores. Is each task processed one at a time in a single core. That is, is it not possible to have multiple tasks processed at the same time on a single core.

Comment: You didn't tell how long it takes to execute all the tasks serially. Is this time close to 100 minutes (no. of cores*25)? Then you have parallelized computations perfectly, and to further decrease the execution time, all you need is to add processor cores - either switch to more powerful machine, or use a machine cluster.

Answer (score 1):

This [Akka tutorial](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/intro/getting-started-first-java.html) shows how Akka can help with parallel tasks.

I don't have any hands-on experience with Akka but my understanding is that it takes care of scaling the application according to configuration at deployment time (eg. number of threads, processes, hosts in cluster...), with little change to the task implementation.

More information on Wikipedia: [The key points distinguishing applications based on Akka actors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akka_(toolkit)#Distinguishing_Features)

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the best thread count, you have to look at the individual task.

If the task is exclusively utilizing the core then no other task can execute on the same core. However, most tasks have some elements of IO such as reading data for processing and writing back the result (assuming that your task is e.g. some complex calculation).

Thread count should be approximately `'amount of cores`' x `'utilization percentage'`
where the utilization percentage is your tuning parameter between zero and one. Find core count dynamically using:

```
int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
```

so

```
int poolcount = Math.round( cores * utilizationFactor);
```

If you subsequently need to scale, you can either scale horizontally or vertically.

Horizontally, more cores, will adjust the throughput, but the utilization may no be linear in this case if there is too much synchronization between the tasks.

Vertically, more computers, definitely gives you more cores to calculate on. So processing farms have always been interesting because of the cost over horizontal scaling. However, the cost of distribution and the cost of distributing the data to compute from has always been the bottlenext.

Hadoop, as commented, solves the problem by distributing data out in partitions and send computation out to the data. That works great for divide-and-conquer types of task with simple merges.

Cassandra, also commented, offers a distributed database where partitioned write are handled through commit-logs and selective read/write consistencies. This basically moves your data around faster, but I suspect you are not too dependent on this.

Apart from these notes, you really need to look inside your task and see how they are conceived and what they should achieve, especially on the divide-and-conquer nature, or sequential/pipeline nature. Akka, as also suggested, provides a lot of help in throughputting asynchronous tasks, and helpful on the synchronization barriers.

Finally, my last piece of advice, is to look at the LMAX Disruptor (http://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/). That should allow you to pass workload between phases with a very high throughput. That (together with optimal core control) might up your speed without having to reconsider the scenario too much.